# Can 作る mean "buy"?

Tags: meaning

I came across this example:

> おかあさん、ほとんど着ない振り袖作ったってしょうがないよ、どうせなら、バーバリーのスーツ買ってよ。 Mom, it's a waste of money to buy me a furisode because I won't have many chances to wear it. If you want to buy me something, please buy me a Burberry's suit.

However, I couldn't find 作る to mean "buy" in the dictionaries I looked at. Is this a slang meaning? Is the translation above correct?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Japanese.SE! Could you please provide context for the "example"? This way we get a little more information about you (at least what books/websites you read) and more information about the sentence at hand. All this will help you to get you a better answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, 作る means 'to make'. (Although you will have to pay for this tailor-made garment.)

The speaker is saying don't get a furisode *made for me*, instead buy me a Burberry suit.